# WPF Datagrid : Find Columns currently visible on screen

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I want to allow the user to add a column and for that column to **appear on screen**. Is there a way to find which columns are currently **on screen**?

Answer (score 1):

The property `Columns` of the Datagrid is an `ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>`.  You will find everithing you need there. If you want to know if any given column is visible, simply check `MyDatagrid.Columns[i].Visibility`

Adding columns in code is simple:

```
DataGridTemplateColumn col = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
MyDatagrid.Columns.Add(col);
```

Comment: this tells you if a column is Visible, Collapsed or Hidden, it does not tell you if it currently on screen